# Breaking up a Rails app into two

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a very lage Rails app that has two distinct sections: the front end and the CMS/Admin. We would like to break up the app into two pieces (for maintenance, as we have distinct teams that work on the front end vs. back end and they could have different release cycles).

One thought was to start a new Admin 2.0 app that has access to the models/schema from the original application, but has its own controllers/views and its own models that extend the original models until it is safe to fully decouple. Is this advisable? If not, what would be an appropriate plan to migrate away from one monolithic codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**warning, this is a bit ranty, and does not go anywhere.**

Having worked on a very large app that operates in the manor you describe (for scalability reasons), I still have mixed opinions (an no conclusive answers).

Currently we operate 3 major apps (+ one or two smaller ones that use a fragment of the schema).

RVW (our admin app): This is the only app that writes, runs on a single server, and is responsible for maintaining the schema.

reevoo.com: ecommerce,  price comparison, stuff like that. This (for historic reasons runs on a slightly different schema, run on a read only slave of RVW, with database views to map the schemas. All writes are done by sticking things on queues that RVW picks up and acts on. This works very well, although the number of random db related issues (mostly related to the views) is an issue. The main problem with this app is the difficulty sharing code (gems work well, I've often dreamed of bringing the schemas into line and sharing the core models in a gem!). We share code between apps using ruby gems. And test using lots of integration tests that cross app boundaries (using [drunit](http://github.com/cwninja/drunit) ([presentation on this available](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/ajax-ria/2-apps-1-test-distributed-ruby-testing))).

reevoomark: very high load b2b app. This has many servers each with a full stack (db server, app server one per node). These have their databases populated with a db export - import batch job. This works very well in the short term, the shear flexibility of it is just ace, but integration testing between apps is very hard.

My advice would be to avoid splitting the apps at all costs, keeping things DRY quickly becomes a major challenge. My advice would be to stick with one app, two sets of routes (selected at startup by environment variables).

This gives you all the advantages of the other solutions, while making code sharing implicit. Splitting your test packs out would make your test cycles shorter and make things more manageable for the two teams. I would avoid working on different code bases, as doing this promotes the apps drifting apart and making code sharing tricky (as in .com).

If you decide do split, have a good set of high level cross app tests. Custom (per app) extensions to a core set of models sounds like a good plan, although with distinct code bases and teams you may still end up with duplicate code. Rails engines should be a good way of sharing the models, but be prepared for model reloading to become a little schizophrenic.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you [namespaced your admin controllers](http://www.claytonlz.com/index.php/2008/05/learning-rails-namespaced-controllers/)? That would be a relatively easy point of subdivision and also avoid many of the negative side effects of forking your code into two apps.

Comment: Yes, we have, but the pain point right now is that the front end team works off a different schedule than the backend team, and the backend team (with a much smaller audience) wants to be able to deploy more often without causing harm to the other team.

Comment: I think you might be trying to solve a management problem by technical means and doing so is exceedingly dangerous as you'll only end up with more management problems if you split the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at [Rails Engines](http://rails-engines.org/news/2009/02/02/engines-in-rails-2-3/)? Added to Rails in 2.3.